# IIS URL Rewriting At Initial Host Request

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with an IIS7 Integrated Pipeline URL Rewrite. 
For my particular scenario I need to rewrite/redirect part of the initial request as follows.

1. User enters `http://savecontoso.com/files/123456789/somefile.html` in the browser address bar.
2. User is redirected to `http://savecontso.com/default.aspx?url=` (results of `url="default.aspx?url={R:1}"`)

This currently works as expected only if I create the initial request as such, `http://savecontoso.com/default.aspx/files/123456789/somefile.html`.

I must note that there is **no actual directory of `/files/` nor `/123456789/` nor any file named `somefile.html`** on the server. I simply need that entire path and filename appended to a query string.

This is my first day working with redirect/rewrite functions using IIS instead of page code behind and I have looked all around learn.iis.net, Google etc to no avail. I understand that rewriting takes place before page requests but for some reason my particular code requires a page request before firing the redirect.

I suspect it is because I am not triggering conditions at the initial request?

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)(/files/\d+/.*html$)" />
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it does not work because of your match pattern:

- the `{R:1}` will only match `(.*)` in your pattern, and will never match `files/123...`
- URL in match pattern always starts with no leading slash: should be `files/\d+...` and not `/files/\d+...`

Try this one instead (works fine for me):

```
<rule name="1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^files/\d+/.*\.html$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="default.aspx?url={R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the help. I had tried all sort of grouping prior to posting. Even broke it down into 4 sections and tried appending for testing. It was the forward slash as the main culprit.  Little details...  Thanks again, really a great help.